# Fork Dialog in MFC application and control the child window problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, libusb

I'm writing an MFC application on Visual Studio 2017 in C++. The application is a user interface for communication with USB device. In my application there's `Start` button. As the user presses the `Start` button, The USB device starts to stream data i.e. it starts sending packets until I'm telling it to stop (I know the maximal size of each packet, but I don't know how many packets I will get). I'm writing the streamed data into a .CSV file.

For this purpose, I'm using a loop board (I still don't have the original board).
I'm trying to simulate a real scenario, so I've written a while loop which sends and reads data.

In my app I also added a `Stop` button, which is supposed to stop the data transmission by exiting this while loop.

Since I wasn't able to do it from my main dialog, I want to create a child dialog which will execute the communication (it will do the while loop which send and receives packages from the loopboard) and I will control this child window from my main dialog.

For this pupose, I've created another class, by Barrnet Chou's advice, as follows:

the `header` file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "libusb.h"

class ChildDlg : public CDialog
{
public:

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnButton1Clicked();
    afx_msg void OnButton2Clicked();
};
```

the `cpp` file:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ChildDlg.h"


#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

// constants definition for packet transfers
constexpr auto VID = 0x04B4;
constexpr auto PID = 0x00F0;
constexpr auto OUT_ENDPOINT_ID = 1;
constexpr auto IN_ENDPOINT_ID = 1;
constexpr auto MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 512;
constexpr int INIT_PACKET_SIZE = 4;

bool flag;

struct libusb_device_descriptor DeviceDescriptor;

libusb_context* context = NULL; //a libusb session
libusb_device_handle* DeviceHandle = NULL; //a device handle


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ChildDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &ChildDlg::OnButton1Clicked)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &ChildDlg::OnButton2Clicked)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void startCommunication() {
    /* Prepare device for communication */
    int RetVal = libusb_init(&context); //initialize a library session

    if (RetVal < 0) {
        // MessageBox(hwnd, "Error in libusb_init", "Error:", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    else {
        libusb_set_debug(context, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation

        DeviceHandle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(context, VID, PID); //these are vendorID and productID for Cypress FX3 specific device
    }

    if (DeviceHandle == NULL) {
        // MessageBox(hwnd, "Cannot open device", "Notice:", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    if (libusb_kernel_driver_active(DeviceHandle, 0) == 1) { //find out if kernel driver is attached
        //detach it
        if (libusb_detach_kernel_driver(DeviceHandle, 0) != 0) {
            // MessageBox(hwnd, "Failed To Detach Kernel Driver!", "Error:", MB_OK);
            return;
        }
    }

    RetVal = libusb_claim_interface(DeviceHandle, 0); //claim interface 0 (the first) of device (desired device FX3 has only 1)

    if (RetVal < 0) {
        // MessageBox(hwnd, "Cannot Claim Interface", "Error:", MB_OK);
        return;
    }
}

void endCommunication() {

    libusb_close(DeviceHandle); //close the device we opened
    libusb_exit(context); //needs to be called at the end 
}


void ChildDlg::OnButton1Clicked() {
    // Insert Start button handler here

    flag = true;

    startCommunication();

    unsigned char* DataOut = new unsigned char[INIT_PACKET_SIZE]; //data to write
    unsigned char* DataIn = new unsigned char[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; //data to read
    int BytesWritten; //used to find out how many bytes were written
    int BytesRead; //used to find out how many bytes were read

    DataOut[0] = 'a'; DataOut[1] = 'b'; DataOut[2] = 'c'; DataOut[3] = 'd'; //some dummy values

    int RetVal = libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (OUT_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), DataOut, sizeof(DataOut), &BytesWritten, 0);

    if (RetVal == 0 && BytesWritten == sizeof(DataOut)) //we wrote the 4 bytes successfully
        MessageBox("Writing Successful!", "Notice:");
    else
        MessageBox("Write Error", "Notice:");
    int counter = 0;

    while ((libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (IN_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), DataIn, sizeof(DataIn), &BytesRead, 200) == 0) && flag == true) {
        std::string cleanData = std::to_string(DataIn[0]) + std::to_string(DataIn[1]) + std::to_string(DataIn[2]) + std::to_string(DataIn[3]);
        MessageBox(cleanData.c_str(), "DATA IN ");
        int RetVal = libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (OUT_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), DataOut, sizeof(DataOut), &BytesWritten, 0); //the out endpoint of current device is 1
        if (RetVal != 0 || BytesWritten != sizeof(DataOut)) MessageBox("Write Error", "Error:");
    }

    while (libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (IN_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), DataIn, sizeof(DataIn), &BytesRead, 200)) {
        MessageBox("Garbage", "Notice:");
    }


    delete[] DataOut; //delete the allocated memory for data

    delete[] DataIn; //delete the allocated memory for data

    endCommunication();
}

void ChildDlg::OnButton2Clicked() {
    flag == false;
}
```

When `Start` button is pressed in the main dialog, I send a message to the child dialog as follows:

```
/* Start Handler */
void CEditableListControlDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    dlg->SendDlgItemMessageA(IDC_BUTTON1, BM_CLICK);

    return;
}
```

and when the `Stop` button is pressen in the main dialog, I send a message to the child dialog as follows:

```
/* Stop Handler */
void CEditableListControlDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    dlg->SendDlgItemMessageA(IDC_BUTTON2, BM_CLICK);
}
```

I have two problems, the first one is that I don't know how to send messages back from the child dialog to the main dialog.

The second problem is that I get a compilation error as follows:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'IDC_BUTTON1': undeclared identifier    

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'IDC_BUTTON2': undeclared identifier
```

But I have no idea how to declare those buttons? In my main dialog I created those buttons by adding them in the `Resource view` and clicking on them twice (which automatically created the adequate handlers)

Is there a way to add a `Resource view` to the child dialog? If there isn't how am I suppose to create those identifiers `IDC_BUTTON1` and `ICD_BUTTON2`?

Thank you.

Comment: *"no window has popped up"* - A child window and a popup window are literally mutually exclusive. If you expect your child window to *"pop up"* you may need to read about [window features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features).

Comment: 1. I am not sure if you have added a message map in the parent window. If not, you could add it, such as ON_MESSGAE. 2.You could check whether the IDs of  `Button1 and Button2` has been modified, or whether the corresponding header file has been added.

Comment: @BARRENTCHOU Thank you for your comment. I checked that, and unfortunately I still can't find the problem, the message map is declared in the header and implemented in the `cpp` file, and I did include `ChildDlg.h` in the main dialog

Comment: I think you could use [GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getparent) where you need to send a message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the button and pop up the window, I suggest you refer to the following example.

1. Create a new dialog and add a new class(like "Test")
2. Add the following code

> ```
> #include "Test.h"
> void CMFCApplication7Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
> {
>   // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
>   Test *pDlg = new Test;
>   pDlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG1, this); //IDD_DIALOG1
>   pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
>   
> }
> ```

If `control` means that you want to operate the controls in the child window through the controls of the parent window, you could see all the controls of the child window by including the child window header file. For example, if the child window is `Test.h`, add `#include Test.h` to the parent window.

Comment: This solution is incomplete because `pDlg` will never be deleted. `pDlg`t should me a member of `CMFCApplication7Dlg`. But anyway, I'm not sure you're answering the question here.

Comment: @BarrnetChou Thank you very much for your comment, I've edited my question, I think now my intention is more clear

Comment: I suggest that you could use `SendMessage()` to send message.

Comment: @BarrnetChou Than you very much for all your help. I'm trying to implement your advice, but having trouble doing it. Could you please look at my edited post? perhaps you'll have a new idea about how can I solve those new problems? Thank you very much once again